# Create Modal in gwtBootstrap3

Tags: bootstrap-modal, gwtbootstrap3

My goal is create a modal with a few input fields and simple functionality on submit button press. I wanna use this gwtbootstrap3 modal :
http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/snapshot/#modals . Is there any example how to create simple modal, with `UiBinder`, which would pop up on button click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, how to create `Modal` with `UiBinder`, in case there will be starters looking for easy answer:

Modal.ui.xml :

```
<b:Modal closable="true" dataKeyboard="true" ui:field="myModal">
    <b:ModalHeader>
        ..
    </b:ModalHeader>
    <b:ModalBody>
        ...
    </b:ModalBody>
</b:Modal>
```

Modal.java

```
import org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Modal;


public class MyModal{

    @UiField
    Modal myModal;

    interface ModalViewUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget,MyModal> {
    }

    private static ModalViewUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(ModalViewUiBinder.class);

    public MyModal() {
        uiBinder.createAndBindUi(MyModal.this);
    }

    public void show() {
        myModal.show();
    }
}
```

and on button click :

```
MyModal modal = new MyModal();
modal.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's exactly what's happening in the demo you've mentioned in your question. Have a look at [it's source code](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/org/gwtbootstrap3/demo/client/application/javascript) (look at the `Modal*` files) to see how it can be done:

```java
// createModal is a Button
createModal.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
        final Modal modal = new Modal();
        modal.setTitle("Java Created Modal");
        modal.setClosable(true);

        // Removed modal's event handlers for brevity
        // ...

        final ModalBody modalBody = new ModalBody();
        modalBody.add(new Span("Create in Java Code!"));

        final ModalFooter modalFooter = new ModalFooter();
        modalFooter.add(new Button("Click ME!", new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
                final Paragraph logEntry = new Paragraph();
                logEntry.setText("Click Event from Modal! (Java Created Modal)");
                logRow.add(logEntry);
            }
        }));

        modal.add(modalBody);
        modal.add(modalFooter);

        modal.show();
    }
});
```